# Socket.io message event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I was trying to learn node and started creating a mashup with socket.io
The message transportation have begin but I have run into some trouble.

The message event is firing multiple times leading to a single message appearing multiple times on the recipient's box. I have routed the socket to `exports.chat` and was wondering if that is causing the problem?

To narrow down the problem: the messages are firing the number of times = the sequence of connection of the client. That is, if a client connects second, his messages will fire twice. three times for the client connecting third.

Here is the code snippet:

```
exports.chat = function(io, pseudoArray, req, res){
    res.render('chat', {title: 'ChatPanel.'});

        var users = 0; 

        io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { // First connection
            users += 1; 
        //  reloadUsers(io, users); 

            socket.on('message', function (data) { // Broadcast the message to all
                if(pseudoSet(socket)) {
                    var transmit = {date : new Date().toISOString(), pseudo : returnPseudo(socket), message : data};
                    socket.broadcast.emit('message', transmit);
                    console.log("user "+ transmit['pseudo'] +" said \""+data+"\"");
                }
            });

            socket.set('pseudo', req.session.user, function(){
                pseudoArray.push(req.session.user);
                socket.emit('pseudoStatus', 'ok');
                console.log("user " + req.session.user + " connected");
            });

            socket.on('disconnect', function () { // Disconnection of the client
                users -= 1;
            //  reloadUsers();
                if (pseudoSet(socket)) {
                    var pseudo;
                    socket.get('pseudo', function(err, name) {
                        pseudo = name;
                    });
                    var index = pseudoArray.indexOf(pseudo);
                    pseudo.slice(index - 1, 1);
                }
            });
        });
};
```

Comment: In your disconnect handler : the part with pseudo.slice should be inside the getter handler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092624/socket-io-removing-specific-listener

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole part of socket.io code has to go outside external.chat function. Socket IO has to bind with the http/app server, you should not handle it within each request.

> the messages are firing the number of times = the sequence of connection of the client

What essentially happening is, each time a new request arrives you are registering a event handler for message, hence it is fired as many times as the you have accessed chat URL.

```
io.socket.on('message', function (data) {...})
```

Comment: i am also facing the same problem can someone help me with this, how this problem was solved, when i changed my code to `io.sockets.on('message'` it doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

So I had the same problem. The solution is to close all your listeners on the socket.on('disconnect') event, this is what my code looks like -

```
 socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                socket.removeAllListeners('send message');
                socket.removeAllListeners('disconnect');
                io.removeAllListeners('connection');
            });
```

Might not need to call it on disconnect, not sure but I do it anyway.

Comment: This doesnt actually solve the problem of when a second client logs on.. just when the one client disconnects. Still haven't fixed my problem :/

Comment: This was a lifesaver. Was trying to debug this for ages. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this misbehavior is because you are attempting to use one of the handful of built-in/reserved event names "message" as an application-specific message. To confirm, change your event name to "message2" or something else and see if the problem goes away. I believe at least "connect", "disconnect", and "message" are reserved. https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events

Answer (score 1):

Link: https://socket.io/docs/v3/listening-to-events/#socketoffeventname-listener

Please use socket.off method to removes the specified listener from the listener array for the event named `eventName`.

```
socket.off("message").on("message", this.UpdateChat);
```

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server can be responsible for several identical event listeners on the client side. If the client has not reloaded (restarted) you have to make sure that the old event listeners are deleted on the client side when establishing a new connection. You can do that with

```
io.socket.removeAllListeners()
```

Answer (score 0):

[**SOCKET.IO v3.x**](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-socket-instance/#Events)

I don't really know why reserve event in socket.io are firing up multiple times, hence I make a logic that fits to our needs and address this problem,

I simply create a global mutable value that could change everytime the 'disconnect' fire up, here's the logic I did

```js
let ACTIVE_USERS = []; //assume the propery of an object is { name, socket_id }
const connections = (socket) => {
  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    //lets check how many times it fires up
    console.log('YOW', reason);

    //mutate the ACTIVE_USERS 
    ACTIVE_USERS = ACTIVE_USERS .filter(user => {
      //lets figure it out if this thing helps us
      if(user.socket_id === socket.id){
        console.log('HEY!!!');

        socket.broadcast.emit('disconnected-user',[
          message: `${user.name} has been disconnected`
        })
      }
    })
  });
}
```

and the result of it is here

[image]