# socket.io Removing specific listener

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I'm using Socket.io v0.9.16 and
Chrome 34

I'm trying to remove a specific listener, or unsubscribe from a specific subscription

Something like this:

```
socket.on('testComplete',function(data){
    console.log('test complete',data);
}); 

function emitTest(){
    console.log('emitting test');
    socket.emit('test','first emit');
}

function removeListener(){
    socket.removeListener('testComplete');
}
```

If I call the `emitTest` function, and then the `removeListener` function, I still see the `'test complete'` message when I call `emitTest` again. The listener should have been removed, if the socket function even works.

I'm looking for a way to remove a *specific* listener that actually works.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418697/how-to-unsubscribe-from-a-socket-io-subscription) says that removeListener doesn't work.

Is there any downside to just doing this:

```
socket.removeListener=function(name){
        if(socket.$events.hasOwnProperty(name)){
            delete socket.$events[name];
        }
    };
```

I marked an answer as correct, but I'm using the above in my code since it works better with my design.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```
//To unsubscribe all listeners of an event
socket.off('event-name');

//to unsubscribe a certain listener
socket.off('event-name', listener);
```

Note that `socket.off`, `socket.removeListener`, `socket.removeAllListeners`, `socket.removeEventListener` are synonyms.

This is tested on socket.io v1.4.3

Comment: I'm using socket.io 2.0.x and can confirm this works both for specific listeners and without specifying a specific listener to just unbind all functions (including anonymous functions).

Comment: With socket.io 2.3.0, the socket.off() event throws an error, if I invoke it without a second parameter, which has to be a function. I presume, the specific function that I want to remove.

Comment: I've managed to remove all the event listeners using `socket.removeAllListeners("news");` found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696077/2691879

Comment: I'm using socket.io version 2.3.0 and `off` is not defined on the server side when obtaining the socket object through `io.on(eventName, (socket) => {...})`. However, `removeListener` works just fine in this case.

Answer (score 54):

You need to pass in the listener function to `removeListener`.

```
function testFun(data){
    console.log('test complete',data);
}

socket.on('testComplete', testFun); 

function emitTest(){
    console.log('emitting test');
    socket.emit('test','first emit');
}

function removeListener(){
    socket.removeListener('testComplete', testFun);
}
```

Comment: Why twice as many? You just have to have a reference to the function you passed in. This is the way all EventEmitters on Node work, as well as the convention in browser libraries. If you have an unknown number of handlers registered for a given event and need to remove them all, I think your solution is sensible though.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2023**: All of the major browsers have decided against supporting `getEventListeners`. Only Chrome supports it from the command line!

If you're not using a function call, or even if you are the following worked for me:

```
getEventListeners(socket)['testComplete'][0].remove()
```

You could even loop through all the listeners attached and remove them.

```
for(var prop in getEventListeners(websocket))
{
    $(getEventListeners(websocket)[prop]).each(function() { this.remove()})
}
```

It's worth pointing out that although this works, it only works in Chrome at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but answers here helped me. Below is a stripped version of my implementation.

```
Angular: 15.2.0 
socket.io-client: 4.6.1 
Chrome: Version 118.0.5993.118 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

What I did was create a Map in my websocket service.
I use it to store the callback function, with the event name as key.

```
eventHandlerMapper: Map<string, (response: any) => void> = new Map();
```

My listen() function looks like so: *(Returning an Observable so my subscriber can handle the payload)*

```
listen(eventName: string): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
        const handler = (data: any) => subscriber.next(data);

        // register handler to socket for this event name
        this.socket.on(eventName, handler);

        // store for unlistening
        this.eventHandlerMapper.set(eventName, handler);
    });
}
```

To unlisten, I simply do this:

```
unlisten(eventName: string): void {
    this.socket.off(eventName, this.eventHandlerMapper.get(eventName));
}
```

By passing the ORIGINAL handler back into this.socket.off(), it unregisters the handler from the socket for the specified event name.

Referencing Socket.io Client API document:

> https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketoffeventname

I then checked the efficacy of my implementation by logging out my socket object and checking its list of registered callback functions, before and after listening/unlistening.