# Socket.io remove listener after being executed

Tags: node.js, function, socket.io

I want to create a listener on a socket.  Then once the listener has been executed, I want the listener to stop listening.  I used this SO:

[socket.io Removing specific listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092624/socket-io-removing-specific-listener)

But I cannot figure out how to have a listener destroy itself.  This is what I am thinking:

```
var ListenEventFunc = function() {
    /* Do some important stuff */
    socket.removeListener('ListenEvent',ListenEventFunc);
}

socket.on('ListenEvent',ListenEventFunc);
```

What is the correct/best way to do this?  Is there anyway I can use the `this` keyword to specify the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
socket.once('ListenEvent', ListenEventFunc);
```

This works because `Socket` inherits from [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter). This doesn't seem to be documented, but [the code references it](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/30ea0b8d7de062e01cb25281f4bab8d32b9910dd/lib/socket.js#L76).