# Remove specific class method listener from socket.io

Tags: socket.io

I am using socket.io-client in a class, such that I do:

```
constructor() {
   socket.on("a", this.a.bind(this));
   socket.off("a", this.a.bind(this));
}
```

But when I construct (both `on` and then `off` fires), the socket still listens to "a".

The way I test this, is to `console.log` on `a` method, enter, and when "a" is received" console logs the event.

I also tried `socket.removeListener`, but it did not work.

Perhaps it is because it is a class method? How can I fix this to work?

Comment: It listens because "keep alive" header in request. You can't fix this.

Comment: @RomanC If I do: `socket.removeAllListeners("a")` it stops this listener, so there is a way to stop it. I am looking for a more specific way

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @RomanC Why do you say that? It does work, to remove all listeners.

Comment: Which protocol socket do you have?

Comment: @RomanC This is Socket.io (using socket.io-client). `on` listens to something, `off` should remove it, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092624/socket-io-removing-specific-listener

Comment: But you can't remove the socket.

Comment: @RomanC I am not trying to remove a socket, I am trying to remove a listener. To close the socket there is a method `socket.close()`

Comment: This you should call on destroy event.

Comment: @RomanC I think you did not understand the question... I have a socket open all the time, for which I add and remove listeners at will. The removal part doesn't work when I bind the listener as a class method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.a.bind(this)` returns a unique function each time so when you then try to use `.off()` with a second call to `.bind()`, you get a different function and thus it won't match the original so `.off()` doesn't find any matching function to remove.

You have to save the original bound function somewhere.  You don't show enough of your code context to know where's a good place to save the original `.bind()` result.

Conceptually, you want to do something like this:

```
// save this somewhere that is per-instance and that both methods can access
// perhaps as an instance variable from the constructor
this.boundA = this.a.bind(this);

ngOnInit() {
   socket.on("a", this.boundA);
}
ngOnDestroy() {
   socket.off("a", this.boundA);
}
```

Demo of the issue:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.a.bind(this) === this.a.bind(this))
  }
  a() {
   
  }
}

let f = new Foo();
```

Comment: I did not know bind creates a unique function, I will change the logic to reflect the above, and will update. (will be a day or so) Thanks.

Comment: @Amit - Try it yourself in the snippet I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Please see the edit, as it still fails to work even if I save in a different varaible

Comment: My mistake, I had a function that is calling the callback function, instead of passing it to the socket. Changed, and it worked