# Express response persists while using socket.io emit

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Currently building a microservice application. The communication between each container is via web sockets and the gateway is a REST gateway.

I want to be able to use emit from within a post request, which is working fine as of right now. But when the the socket is to handle a `on` event and then reply back via the gateway using a express response object, that object is not closed with a `response.json` call. The object is still alive inside another `on` event inside the same route, which then makes the new request generate the error, `headers cannot be set after they are send`. This makes sense, but how do I ensure that the new request, gets a new response object ?

**First request**
gateway -> (ws) -> microserver -> (ws) -> gateway -> (http) user
**Second request**
gateway -> (ws) -> microserver -> (ws) -> gateway -> ERROR

**Gateway snippet**:

```
app.post("/api/user/create", function (req, res) {
  console.log("Create request");
  let token = req.get("Authentication");
  let userData = req.body;
  ioClientUsers.emit("create", {
    "token": token,
    "userData": userData
  });
  ioClientUsers.once("user created", success => {
    console.log(res.headersSent);
    if (success) {
      return res.json({
        "status": "created"
      }); 
    } else {
      return res.json({
        "status": "not created"
      });
    }
  });
  ioClientUsers.once("user not created", () => {
    console.log(res.headersSent);
    res.json({
      "status": "not created"
    });
  });
});
```

**Microservice snippet**

```
 socket.on("create", createObj => {
 console.log(createObj);
 userController.createUser(createObj.token, createObj.userData, (err, success) => {
   console.log(err, success);
   if (err) {
     socket.emit("user not created");
   } else {
     socket.emit("user created", success);
   }
 });
});
```

**EDIT** 
Just posting again, so that if anybody else has the same problem, either the one answer to this or this edit solves the problem:

```
 app.post("/api/user/create", function (req, res) {
  let token = req.get("Authentication");
  let userData = req.body;
  ioClientUsers.emit("create", {
    "token": token,
    "userData": userData
  });
  ioClientUsers.once("user created", userCreated);
  ioClientUsers.once("user not created", userNotCreated);

  function userCreated(success){
    if (success) {
      res.json({
        "status": "created"
      }); 
    } else {
      res.json({
        "status": "not created"
      });
    }  
    rmListner();
  }
  function userNotCreated(){
    console.log(res.headersSent);
    res.json({
      "status": "not created"
    });
    rmListner();
  }

  function rmListener(){
    ioClientUsers.removeListener("user created", userCreated);
    ioClientUsers.removeListener("user not created", userNotCreated);
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to remove your listeners after you call `res.json`. And you might want some way of making sure that your `socket.emit` calls specify, somewhere somehow, something that can tell the `ioClientUsers.once` callbacks that *this callback is for you*, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Yeah I see where you are going with this. The problem is tho, that I don't think there is a way to "unsubscribe" or remove the instance of the callback. At least that's something I have to research.

Comment: There is a way to unsubscribe with socket.io. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092624/socket-io-removing-specific-listener -- you'll have to redesign your functions so you can remove them after any `res.json` is called

Comment: Hmm, yes that's properly the way to do it. The next problem is that `res.json` is returning out of the function, which makes it impossible to exec the function after...

Comment: Just be aware, still, that if 'app.post' is called a second time before the first 'app.post' is done, whle it's still waiting for 'user created' or 'user not created', then **the first time user created callback happens** will (if I'm reading this correctly) hit the callback for both the first and second `app.post`s, which is why i recommended you come up with a way to distinguish which callback is being run.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Hmm, have to test if it will work if i pass the response object to the socket, and then use that object again in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this

```
app.post("/api/user/create", function (req, res) {
  console.log("Create request");
  let token = req.get("Authentication");
  let userData = req.body;
  ioClientUsers.emit("create", {
    "token": token,
    "userData": userData
  });

  function createdCallback(success) {
    if (success) {
      sendStatus('created')
    } else {
      sendStatus('not created')
    }
  }

  function notCreatedCallback() {
    sendStatus('not created')
  }

  function sendStatus(status) {
    console.log(res.headersSent);
    // UNSUBSCRIBE YOUR LISTENERS HERE
    ioClientUsers.removeListener("user created", createdCallback);
    ioClientUsers.removeListener("user not created", notCreatedCallback);
    res.json({'status': status})
  }

  ioClientUsers.once("user created", createdCallback);
  ioClientUsers.once("user not created", notCreatedCallback);
});
```

The socket listeners are all removed before `res.json` is called. See if that works.

Comment: That's funny, I did came to the same conclusion. See **edit**